# VSTS Service Hooks - On Build Creation / Edition

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are looking to add a service hook to call an API when any of our build definitions are edited or when someone creates a new build definition. In the list of options available for WebHooks, I only see an option "Build Complete" with respect to builds (as shown below).

Is there a way, we can add to the list of triggers on VSTS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t such feature available in VSTS now, there is a user voice that you can vote: [add service hook for build definition create/delete/modify](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31453171-add-service-hook-for-build-definition-create-delet)